# How to call Coroutine in lateUpdate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I love coroutines. They are like self sustaining code but the problem is that they are called at a specific time in the unity's frame. According to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), most coroutines are called after update but before animations. I want to have a coroutine type system that can be called after the internal animation update but before the Scene Rendering. This is because I am editing 3D model transforms after the animations (not animation dependent). How to do this? I am working in C#.

Answer (score 4):

As it is described on the link you provided yourself, this is not possible. The engine works the way it works, this cannot be altered from "script level".
What you could do however, if you insist to use coroutines, is to make them just "prepare the execution of your code", and leave the job to `LateUpdate()`.
To achieve this, you should do something like (kinda pseudo code as it's untested)

```
bool hasToUpdate = false; //class variable

private void LateUpdate() {
    if (hasToUpdate == false) { return; } //I don't like "!" or leave "{}"
    //do the stuff you want to do between 'game logic' and 'rendering'
    //the thing you most probably do now in your coroutine code
    hasToUpdate = false;
}

private void YourCoroutine() {
    //if happened what you want / there was the expected
    //user interaction, yield returned, etc, set class variables
    //to the proper value (if there's anything like that), etc:
    //i.e. move out values from coroutine code to class
    //level and set calculated values you need to set, then:
    hasToUpdate = true;
}
```

This way, your coroutine task will execute exactly where you want and exactly the way you want BUT, even though this should work, it feels "a little hacky" to me.

Anyway. It's hard to tell more without the specific problem you have or without your code, but I hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It gave me an idea based on your answer.

Comment: @Darnell You're very welcome. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I used a UnityEvent to register callbacks that will be performed in a LateUpdate